# How to make new bootstrap 4 card to get added to left of page when adding through ngFor dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

The cards created is getting added on the right of the page, kindly suggest how to get the cards added to left. Using only card class the cards are getting expanded when using the filter. So switched to the card-column.

```
<div class="card-columns">
          <div class="card shadow rounded" *ngFor="let emp of employee | customerFilter:searchTerm">
            <div class="card-header bg-info text-white" (click)="viewDetails(emp.id)">
             <strong> {{emp.name}} </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="alignleft p-3">
              <img class="imageClass" [src]="emp.photoPath"/>
            </div>
            <div class="alignright p-3">
            <h3>{{emp.fname}}</h3>
            <p>{{emp.Address}}</p>
            <p>{{emp.phoneNumber}}</p>
            </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: can you give a stackblitz?

Comment: i used your html and create a stackblitz. its coming fine. See it at :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auyuks

Comment: Nothing in the posted code seems to be causing this, either post the html wrapping this piece of code or post. I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dax52efb/) to test, add more code to this one

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code on Stackbliz and fiddle, I am trying to trace the issue.